# regex token for pipe delimited text

Tags: regex

how to grab first, second, third, forth and fifth token of the following string using reg expression?

1|123|y|1108392390371|19232

I was able to grab the last part of the string using the following \b(\d+)\s*(\w+)$ but i am not sure how to read 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th token .. please help!

I would like to read one token at a time with reg expression

Comment: One way is by **writing** a regex.

Comment: i was able to grab the last part of the string using the following 
\b(\d+)\s*(\w+)$ 

but i am not sure how to read 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th token .. please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex

```
(\d+)\|(\d+)\|(\w+)\|(\d+)\|(\d+)
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL1qY8/1)

It uses the concept of [capturing groups](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)